# Programming an old console, Magnavox Odyssey 2?

Tags: c, assembly, console

Ive been searching around and I couldnt find anything on how to really begin programming for the Odyssey 2. I thought it was be kind of fun to mess around with one, to maybe try and program a simple game. But I wanted to know how I could begin. Like for example what is the console coded with, assembly? C?
Is there any example code online? Are there some tutorials?
I have been trying to find some, but have had no success.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Try searching for 'homebrew'. That seems to be the word used when people write their own software for consoles.

Comment: http://www.atarihq.com/danb/o2.shtml . The processor is an Intel 8048 so if you want C you'll need to find a C compiler that targets it.  You'll probably want a cartridge with a socket you put something like an EPROM into.  The link references an assembler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has only 64-bytes of memory, so yes, you need to use assembly.
There is an open-source, well commented game [Kill the attacking aliens](http://soeren.informationstheater.de/g7000/ktaa.html) which should help you get started. When in doubt, you can also check the source codes of Odyssey² open-source emulators [o2em](http://o2em.sourceforge.net/).

There is also a good deal of documentation of the system [here](http://soeren.informationstheater.de/g7000/) ([this page](http://soeren.informationstheater.de/g7000/toc.html) in particular).

Comment: Thank you so much, honestly thank you. Now time to mess around and make some magic happen haha :)

Comment: A token of your thanks would be to accept his answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

It has an Intel 8048 CPU, so you're probably pretty much stuck with assembly language -- I don't know of any compilers that target an 8048, and with only a couple hundred bytes of RAM available (only 64 bytes of that for general-purpose use), it doesn't seem like a good target for a compiler either. There are a few 8048 assemblers around, mostly of them freely downloadable. You can also dig up a few Odessey 2 emulators if you do a little looking (again, at least some are free).